# I want to Change Data-filter Default Tab in bootstrap

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying here to make my default tab to be panel and only panel pics should be seen but unlucky to get this.
when i am applying ACTIVE class to other tab it shows default active but will all pics not only the particular tabs pic. I tried a lot but no luck hope this is just a small problem for you.

```
 <ul class="portfolio-filter">

                    <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter=".panels">Panels</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".electric">Electricals Measuring Instruments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".power">Engineering / Power tools</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".saftey">Safety equipments / Welding Materials</a></li>
                     <li><a  href="#" data-filter="*">All Products</a></li>

                </ul><!--/#portfolio-filter-->


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mousescroll.js"></script>
    <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="form/vendor.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i placed this below my page just before body end tag and its solved
```

$(function(){

```
  var $container = $('#container');


  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
    masonry : { columnWidth: 70 },
    filter: '.panels'
  });


  var PageLoadFilter = '.panels';
  $container.isotope({ filter: PageLoadFilter});

  $('#portfolio button').click(function(){
    $container.isotope({
      filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
    });
  });

});
```